# Java Voice Biometric

Tags: java, voice-recognition, biometrics

I want to develop an application based on *Voice Biometric Recognition*.

Specifically, I want to develop an application which will record a voice from the telephone, and identify the speaker. If the same person calls again it will recognize the voice. Like other Biometric applications do here my need is to do a voice biometric. Are there any URLs or examples which will help me. I searched but not able to find a solution.

```
FreeSpeech is a text-independent speaker verification system that verifies a caller's identity
```

I want to achieve the above one FreeSpeech Recognition in my application.

Is it possible to do the below things by using any Open Source.

1. The individual records a voice print, then
2. The system keeps track of the voice prints and can distinguish recordings from live speech

If yes, can you please provide me a URL or example which will help me.

Well, I got the light from [This](http://marf.sourceforge.net/) Url to achieve the above task but not able to get the expected out put.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After wasting 20 to 25 Hrs, Finally I got the solution by using MARF Framework.
I got the sample app from the http://sourceforge.net/projects/marf/files/Applications/%5Bf%5D%20SpeakerIdentApp/0.3.0-devel-20060226/
And for now, it's working fine for me. This links is very useful for me to make the sample app executable. http://marf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For the record, here is another Java based speaker recognition framework named Recognito which can be integrated in a matter of minutes instead of hours : https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito
It didn't exist at the time this question was raised but it might be useful to people checking today...

Answer (score 7):

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609528/java-voice-recognition) previous SO post in which various Java Speech Recognition Engines are described such as [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/).

Comment: Thanks @npinti, do you have any experience on this?.

Comment: @subodh No, I have never used any speech engine. You should be able to find something online though.

Comment: I do not know if it is possible or not, like I have said, I have never used such a framework. I think that the second point might be hard to achieve. Maybe you can take a look at some signal processing material.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this domain so please take my answer as is , it's not an authorative one... I think you have different ways to achieve your goals :
- finding a Java library is one , the most natural one
- recording the voice in Java then applying one of the several algorithms available for such job , you may find many research papers dealing with that subject
- depending from the architecture choices, you may find different libraries implemented in C dealing with voice signal, using JNI or JNA is one way to deal with C/C++ libraries, Web Services or CORBA are other ways to achieve this....

HTH
Jerome

Comment: I've one used SciLab behind Java application to do cepstral analysis of signal to check some biometrics from human voice.