# Speaker Recognition in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, security, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speaker

I want to track voice by using voice recognition functionality in iPhone App for security purposes.

Every user can record his/her voice and open the application by his/her voice being recognized only which was recored and stored in a database.

Does anyone have an idea or sample application for this functionality and how to implement it within an iPhone Application?

Comment: Try to use Ispeech SDK. http://www.ispeech.org/speech.recognition.demo

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota nope. That's not what OP wants. OP wants to identify a user by his voice, and not merely recognizing speech.

Comment: H2CO3 : you are right..
SibaPrasadHota : I want the same as H2CO3 said.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Mobbeel](http://www.mobbeel.com/). They have biometric security solutions (iris, voice, face, hand geometry) for Android and iOS devices.  You might want to check out [Nuance's biometric solutions](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-solution/customer-service-solutions/solutions-services/inbound-solutions/voice-authentication-biometrics/index.htm) also.  There is an open source [biometric solution on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/voicebiometrics/), but it does not seem to be very active.  Also check out this [QA on a Java voice biometric solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724454/java-voice-biometric).